# ionic2 How to get input data to other page

Tags: html, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

i would like to know about, how to get {this.username} in HomePage to ListPagePage

and i get error >> `EXCEPTION: Error in ./HomePage class HomePage - inline              template:16:8 caused by: this.navParams.get is not a function`

so sorry i'm not good English. T^T Thank you in advance for your help

home.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      GitHub
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content>
    <ion-list inset>
        <ion-item>
            <ion-label>Search</ion-label>
            <ion-input [(ngModel)]="username" type="text"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
</ion-list >
    <div padding>
        <button ion-button block (click)="changePage()">Search</button>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

home.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { NavController, NavParams} from 'ionic-angular';
import { ListPagePage } from '../list-page/list-page';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {


  public username;
 public foundRepos;
 public repos;

  constructor(
              private nav: NavController,
              private navParams :NavParams ) {

  }


changePage(username){
  console.log(this.username);
  this.nav.push(ListPagePage, (this.username));
}

}
```

list-page.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      GitHub
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
<ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of  foundRepos" (click)="itemClicked($event,item)">


      <h2> {{ item.name }}</h2>
      <p> {{ item.description }}</p>
    </ion-item>

  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

list-page.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { HomePage } from '../home/home';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-list-page',
  templateUrl: 'list-page.html',

})
export class ListPagePage {

static get parameters() {
    return [[NavController], [NavParams],[Http]];
  }

public foundRepos : any
username: any;

  constructor(public navParams: NavParams,
              public http: Http,
              public nav: NavController,
              public homepage : HomePage ) {

    this.navParams = navParams;
    this.username = this.navParams.get(this.username);
    this.http = http;
    this.http.get("https://api.github.com/users/${this.username}/repos")
    .subscribe(data => {
          this.foundRepos = data.json();
      },
      err => console.error(err),
      () => console.log('getRepos completed')
      );
     }
     }
```

Answer (score 2):

Change `this.nav.push(ListPagePage, (this.username));` to

`this.nav.push(ListPagePage, {username: this.username});`

And then get it by changing `this.username = this.navParams.get(this.username);`
to:

`this.username = this.navParams.get('username');`

What you're then doing is basically sending an object with the name of 'username' in your NavParams. Then the NavParams can retrieve the value of the name 'username' by calling the `.get('username);` which will return the value set.

**edit** found quite a bit of errors in your code and things I don't understand why you're doing them. Try this code: (keep html files the same)

List-page.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-list-page',
  templateUrl: 'list-page.html',

})
export class ListPagePage {

public foundRepos : any
username: any;

  constructor(navParams: NavParams,
              public http: Http,
              public nav: NavController) {

    this.username = navParams.get('username');

    // no need for this assignment --> if you declare http public in constructor, it's already accessible by `this.http`
    // this.http = http;

    this.http.get("https://api.github.com/users/${this.username}/repos")
    .subscribe(data => {
          this.foundRepos = data.json();
      },
      err => console.error(err),
      () => console.log('getRepos completed')
      );
     }
}
```

And Home.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { NavController, NavParams} from 'ionic-angular';
import { ListPagePage } from '../list-page/list-page';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

      public username;
      public foundRepos;
      public repos;

       constructor(
              private nav: NavController,
              private navParams :NavParams ) {

       }

     // removed parameter since you don't call it with one in your html file.
     changePage(){
       console.log(this.username);
       this.nav.push(ListPagePage, {username: this.username});
     }

}
```

Comment: thank you very much , But it still Error   "EXCEPTION: Error in ./HomePage class HomePage - inline              template:16:8 caused by: this.navParams.get is not a function"

Comment: @fongfuse edited the answer, copy paste my code in your typscript files and try it :)

Comment: @lvaro18 hi, I found a new problem . Help me pls . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41769677/how-to-count-json-data-item-ionic2