# How to count json data item ionic2

Tags: html, json, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I find a new problem,
I would like to count `@NAME` to set array `FACET[]` for show `@KEY`

Myjson

```
  "    RESULT":{
              "FACET":[
                { "@NAME" : "creator", 
                  "@COUNT" : "20",
                  "FACET_VALUES":[
                    {
                      "@KEY":"Book Company1",
                      "@VALUE":"13"},
                    {
                      "@KEY":"Book Company1์",
                      "@VALUE":"10"}],
                { "@NAME" : "lang", 
                  "@COUNT" : "70",
                  "FACET_VALUES":[
                    {
                      "@KEY":"tha",
                      "@VALUE":"33"},
                    {
                      "@KEY":"eng",
                      "@VALUE":"42"}
                   ],
                { "@NAME" : "bnb", 
                  "@COUNT" : "64",
                  "FACET_VALUES":[
                    {
                         .
                         .
                         .

              ]
```

.

```
     optionsFn(): void {
            this.http.get("my_url")
                        .subscribe(data =>{
                                 this.date=data.json().RESULT.FACET; //get @NAME
                        },error=>{
err => console.error(err),
                           () => console.log('getRepos completed')
            );
        console.log(this.date);

            console.log(this.date);
            this.goToapply()
      }

      goToapply(){

       this.http.get("my_url")
                        .subscribe(data =>{
                                 this.foundRepos=data.json().RESULT.FACET[0,1,2,3.4......].FACET_VALUES; ///get @KEY
                        },error=>{
                            console.log(error);
                        } );

      }
```

..

```
    <ion-label>Filterr</ion-label>
          <ion-select [(ngModel)]="refine" (ionChange)="optionsFn();">
            <ion-option value="..." *ngFor="let item of date">{{item["@NAME"]}},({{item["@COUNT"]}})</ion-option>
          </ion-select>
<ion-list>          
          <ion-item *ngFor="let item of foundRepos" (click)="itemClicked($event,item)">
            <h3> {{ item[@KEY"] }}</h3>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
```

This `value="..."` I want to keep it to `string` for to use, but zi have know idea.

> example : count `@NAME = 3 (creator,lang,bnb)` ,and get `value="..." = 0,1,2 (0==creator ,1==lang ,2==bnb)` 
>   When I select `lang` I get `1` , I use this to `FACET[1].FACET_VALUES` , So that I get `@KEY`

Sorry to write wrong. My english isn't very good.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. there's just a tip that I would like to point out to you. You shoud get a bit better with words. Not the English language in particular but more about explaining your current result and your desired result. I believe this will force you into learning english at a much faster pace than you're currently doing. (coming from a non-native speaker)

"I would like to count@NAME to set array FACET[] for show @KEY"

So, with the returned JSON we can do a couple of things, which do not get quite clear from immediately looking at your question (did a +1 since I don't believe it's of bad quality or isn't a good question).

So there are 3 things I should  cover in my post

- Counting the amount that NAME occurs
- Setting an array for the FACET
- Showing the KEY per FACET which seems to be the end goal.

Ok

**Counting the amount that NAME occurs**

So you basically already got this answer. You submitted this code

`this.http.get("my_url")
    .subscribe(data =>{
          this.date=data.json().RESULT.FACET; //get @NAME
});`

Which means you already have access to the FACET array. Counting the amount that NAME occurs can be done either by creating a for loop and checking if the name is not undefined (thus incrementing an int) or *counting* on the fact that NAME is always defined, thus just calling `this.date.size()` (if this.date is set correctly of course)

**get an array for the FACET**

this, you're already doing by assiging the `this.date = data.json().RESULT.FACET`. Your `this.date` now contains an array holding your FACET objects. Just see it like this: JSON (with comments which is not possible in JSON but just for demonstration purposes) =

```
{ FACET: // declare the main object, called FACET 
  [     // declaring the FACET as an Array ([] is for creating a list)
    {id: 2} //initializing a child of the FACET array
    ,{id: 3} //initializing the second FACET child.
  ]
}
```

So, this pseudo (not realistic) JSON holds 2 objects, having `id = 2` and `id = 3`

Ok, now you should understand a bit of JSON, let's take a look at how your code looks (taking a Businnes with multiple offices and multiple employees per office into account)

```
{
  OFFICES" : [
       {
         "id" : "1",
         "location" : "New York",
         "employees" : [
           {"id" : "1", "fullName" : "Jon Skeet"},
           {"id" : "2", "fullName" : "Random Stranger"}
         ]
     },
     {
        "id" : "2",
        "location" : "Amsterdam",
        "employees" : [
            {"id" : "1", "fullName" : "Ivaro18"},
            {"id" : "2", "fullName" : "Some-Random Stranger"}
         ]
      }
  ]
}
```

This code is basically the same as your code. And the question your asking now is, taking the code from my answer, how to get all the id's or names of all the employees. (get all names of keys of facet objects)

Now let's show you in typescript

```
someFunction() {
   this.http.get('someUrl').map(response => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(response.json())); // check what you actually retrieve

      let decoded = response.json();
      for(let office of decoded.OFFICE) {
         console.log(office.location);

         for(let employee of office.employees) {
            console.log(employee.fullName);
         } 
      }
   });
}
```

Expected output of this program

```
> New York
> Jon Skeet
> Random Stranger
> Amsterdam
> Ivaro18
> Some-Random Stranger
```

I think this pseudo code will get you to think a bit out-of-the-box and find the answer to your question. If you can't elaborate more on **what you want as output** I will be glad to help you at any time (even weekends) just comment and I'll respond when I have the time!

Comment: Please read my explaining below answer2 ,But I don't know to set option value="..." to keep number 0,1,2,3 respectively

Answer (score 0):

@Ivaro18  thanks for your answers. 
I want to counting the amount that `@NAME` 
for setting an array for the FACET 
and showing the KEY per `FACET[]` which seems to be the end goal.

Yes, you totally know what I meant.
But i want output is every `@KEY` of that `FACET[]`

Example :

```
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="refine" (ionChange)="optionsFn();">
            <ion-option value="..." *ngFor="let item of date">{{item["@NAME"]}},({{item["@COUNT"]}})</ion-option>
          </ion-select>
<ion-list>          
          <ion-item *ngFor="let item of foundRepos" (click)="itemClicked($event,item)">
            <h3> {{ item[@KEY"] }}</h3>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
```

.

```
 optionsFn(): void {
            this.http.get("my_url")
                        .subscribe(data =>{
                                 this.date=data.json().RESULT.FACET; //get @NAME
                        },error=>{
err => console.error(err),
                           () => console.log('getRepos completed')
            );
        console.log(this.date);

            console.log(this.date);
            this.goToapply()
      }

      goToapply(){

       this.http.get("my_url")
                        .subscribe(data =>{
                                 this.foundRepos=data.json().RESULT.FACET[0,1,2,3.4......].FACET_VALUES; ///get @KEY
                        },error=>{
                            console.log(error);
                        } );

      }
```

from above ion-select is show `creator` , `lang` and `bnb` ,I want to If When I select `lang` `ion-option value="..."` 
to keep `number` of `"@NAME"`

- example counting amount of `@NAME` is 3 and
- when I select `creator` is ion-option value="..." << is 0
- when I select `lang` is ion-option value="..." << is 1
- when I select `bnb` is ion-option value="..." << is 2

and If i get `value` ,I take it to  `goToapply()` for set `FACET[]`

- example I  select `bnb` I get value =2 and `console.log this.refine`
  is show `2`
- take it(2) to  `let p = this.refine` , so that `p = 2`
- take p to `this.foundRepos=data.json().RESULT.FACET[p].FACET_VALUES;` for show `@KEY` in `ion-list`

When I select `lang` output is

```
> tha
> eng
```

Comment: @Ivaro18 But I don't know to set option value="..." to keep number 0,1,2,3 respectively

Comment: Aaaaaah okay my bad sorry, your answer **is** clear but I just read over it. For binding to the value, try `<ion-option [value]="date.size() - 1">` or `<ion-option [attr.value]="date.size() -1">` (note: can't test because I'm on mobile, you might need to replace `date.size()` with `date.length()` but I'm not sure

Comment: @Ivaro18  Sorry but error : Cannot read property 'length' of undefined.

Comment: Ok add in an `*ngIf=date` on your `ion-select`

Comment: @Ivaro18  Hey guy, I have the answer!  `<ion-option [value]="i" *ngFor="let item of date;let i = index">{{item["@NAME"]}},({{item["@COUNT"]}})</ion-option>` Thank you for trying to do everything for me.